# How can I adjust axis' label in data.plot()?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
data.plot(kind='kde', subplots=True, layout=(3,3), sharex=False, figsize= (10,10),fontsize=8)
pyplot.show()
```

[see figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iU7M.png)

I want to make that 'density' smaller and more white space between those figures!

Comment: you can use `plt.tight_layout()` to autoadjust the subplots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plt.subplots_adjust(wspace= ).  The float you assign to wspace will determine the distance between subplots as a fraction (or multiple) of subplot width.  Once you have separated your subplots, you will see that you won't want to adjust the y_label fontsize since it is optimized by pyplot.  See the example below:

```
data.plot(kind='kde', subplots=True, layout=(1,3), sharex=False, figsize= (10,3))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]